# Create dataframe from nested dictionary with different array lengths

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to convert a dictionary of nested dictionaries to a dataframe, which will then be converted to a csv.

I'm only interested in pulling all keys and values from the main key, `properties`.

`dict_keys(['addedAt', 'vid', 'canonical-vid', 'merged-vids', 'portal-id', 'is-contact', 'profile-token', 'profile-url', 'properties', 'form-submissions', 'identity-profiles', 'merge-audits'])`

In properties, the values are also stored as a key-value pair. Here is a snippet of what it looks like:

`dict_items([('firstname', {'value': 'John'}), ('associatedcompanyid', {'value': '54321'}), ('hs_analytics_last_url', {'value': 'https://website.com/contactus/'}), ('more keys', {'value': 'string'})`

The following code seems to do the job. But it only creates a data frame for one row.

`dfobj = pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k, v in contact_dict['properties'].items() ]))`

How would I create a for loop that gets all keys, values -and within values, the actual value- from the nested dictionary, and turn it into a dataframe?

The challenge is that not every record will have the same array length under `properties`. So I've been receiving this error `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`.

Here is that code I ran:

`df = pd.DataFrame(contact_dict)`

`df1 = df.transpose()`

And here is the error I received in full. Line 107 is where `df = pd.DataFrame(contact_dict)` is located. Any tips are greatly appreciated:

````
  File "C:\Users\alexs\Desktop\pythonenvs\get_hubspot_2.py", line 107, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(contact_dict)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 411, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 257, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 77, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 368, in extract_index
    raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length")
ValueError: arrays must all be same length```
````

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @AMC. I edited this to include the error message. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: I should mention I tried pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in contact_dict.items()])). But I’m trying to go one more level further in order to extract the value in the value keys within properties.